# How to do the following in case of Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saas, multi-tenant

**How to do subdomains & seperated databases for a rails app as shown in tutorial below for php**

I am a newbie with ruby & ruby on rails as well so I would like now that is any thing possible which shown in [this tutorial by anatgarg in php](http://anantgarg.com/2013/06/10/build-a-php-saas-app-from-scratch/)

1. subdomains
2. multiples databases
3. database switching based on subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can see screencasts @ Railscasts episode [#221 Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)
2. Actually, I never use multiples databases, but I have try use multiples schemas with postgresql, see @ Railscasts episode [#389 Multitenancy with PostgreSQL pro](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql)
3. You can use gem [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) for switching schema based on subdomain

I can't explain one by one because it would be too long to be explained. Hope this help

Comment: thanks @anonymousxxx i think these will definitly help to get started up :)